# Jquery easyautocomplete function doesn't work on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm loading input field dynamically with jquery.

```
<div class="cities"><input class="addCity" type="text" id="city"></div>
```

But jQuery easyAutoComplete function doesn't seem to work on it. Works well on static input fields.

```
jQuery("#city").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Comment: there is nothing with id "city", only "cities". So try jQuery(".cities").easyAutocomplete(options);  "#" sign is used with ids, not with classes

Comment: No, it doesn't! i had that ID on my php file.

Comment: I know for the click functions, you need to add a selector for dynamically loaded contents but just not sure. How this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ajax success function do:

```
success: function(input_html) {
    $('#input-place').html(input_html);
    $('#input-id').easyAutocomplete(options);
}
```

Bind easyAutocomplete after inserting input in DOM

Comment: Bind all events (plugins) after inserting element in DOM. Or use $(document).on('click', '#dynamic-elem', function(){ code here }); for native jquery events.